# Why AWS EC2 ubuntu machine can't start if a volume which is not root is full?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04

As the title describes, I have some Ubuntu (16.04/18.04) machines on AWS EC2, which contains 2 volumes, 1 root, and 1 for /var/logs.

In case the /var/logs volume is full, the machine won't start and I'll receive "Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown: Instance initiated shutdown".

My question is, why won't the machine start if this volume is full? is it due to some system service that will abort the boot if it can't write to /var/logs? is it related to the way AWS handles full volumes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to "the way AWS handles full volumes". AWS doesn't handle full volumes in any special way. This is a Unix operating system issue. The `/var/logs` folder is used by most system processes. That is where important things like your system's boot log are written. It makes sense that space on that volume would be a requirement to boot.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I agree that it makes sense, but do you happen to know what exactly fails the boot? is it a specific service?

Comment: It's difficult to know which specific service fails, since that service can't log an error message saying it failed... I would say it's probably every single important service, probably even the Linux kernel itself that is failing, because it can't write any logs.